# Using token/constraints in AspNetCore IApplicationBuilder.Map

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

It is possible to use tokens/constraints when using IApplicationBuilder Map method?

Let's make an example. I am branching my aspnet core pipeline into different nested applications. I would like to map also the versioning of those applications so instead of writing

```
app.Map( "/branch1", builderConfig => {
    [...]
});
```

I would like to use something like this

```
app.Map( "/branch1/{v{version:apiVersion}}/", builderConfig => {
    [...]
});
```

The constraint in the new path would be resolved at runtime.

I am using latest AspNetCore version (`2.2.102`)

Is that even possible?

Comment: There is already a library for versioning APIs, have you tried that? It might be a better option for you. https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/How-to-Version-Your-Service

Comment: That's exactly the library I am using @DavidG. However my question is a little bit different and focus on mapping a dynamic path within AspNet Core. Not properly on versioning. Sorry if it is not that clear...

Comment: Maybe you could use `app.MapWhen` and have some logic based on the requested URL?

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I handle api versioning with MapWhen for example?

Comment: By doing your own string analysis on the path, it may feel a bit nasty but you can do anything you need to in the delegate method.